# ImportError to import cv2 on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, neural-network, computer-vision, opencv

I I'm following this tutorial to start with YOLOV4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5pYh1rFnNZs

But when trying to import OpenCV with "import cv2" in python terminal the following message appears:

```
** On entry to DGEBAL parameter number  3 had an illegal value
** On entry to DGEHRD  parameter number  2 had an illegal value
** On entry to DORGHR DORGQR parameter number  2 had an illegal value
** On entry to DHSEQR parameter number  4 had an illegal value
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\LUCINALDO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
```

I already tried to update numpy, OpenCV or install other libraries but the error persists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your numpy is not up to date or the problem is might be related with your pip version, so you need to upgrade it or delete it and install it again. You can make it via typing to terminal tha commands below in order.

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

and then

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

If you are using Mac OS you can try this one too

```
python3 -m pip install numpy -I
```

If you are using Ubuntu try this one

```
pip3 uninstall numpy
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy
```

Comment: I just tried, continue with the same problem :/

Comment: Could you try with `pip uninstall numpy ` and then try it with conda such as `conda install -c conda-forge numpy`

Answer (score 1):

I found out! For some reason the numpy 1.19.4 version has some bug on windows, just uninstall and install a previous version

```
pip uninstall numpy
```

and then

```
pip install numpy==1.19.3
```

As this source guided: https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/1030

Comment: as I understand it, numpy's warning is actually not a bug in numpy but in Windows. numpy only warns of it since 1.19.4. when you stick with 1.19.3, the bug is still there, but without the warning.